# Yii2. Разделить checkBoxList на 2 колонки

Tags: yii2

Есть связанные модели, связка по типу many-to-many. И надо мне для редактирования вывести список в виде checkBoxList, но в 2 колонки.

Я разделил массив всех видов платежей на 2 части, и вывел вот таким образом:

```
<div class="row">
<?php foreach ($dividedPayments as $payments):?>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'payments_ids')->checkboxList(ArrayHelper::map($payments,'id','title')); ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[image: Две колонки чекбоксов]

Однако, значения проставленные в первой колонке не запоминаются в базе. 
Оно и понятно, ведь если глянуть, что передает форма, то можно увидеть вот такое:

```
Places[payments_ids]:
Places[payments_ids][]:4
Places[payments_ids][]:9
Places[payments_ids][]:10
Places[payments_ids]:
Places[payments_ids][]:15
Places[payments_ids][]:20
Places[payments_ids][]:21
```

и в `Yii::$app->request->post()` имеем только один массив с 15, 20, 21.

А теперь, знатоки, внимание вопрос! Как сделать так, что-бы работало?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам задал, сам и отвечу: 
Все решается значительно проще. Надо просто переопределить вывод самого чекбокса через анонимную функцию. Вот как у меня это получилось сделать:

```
<div class="row">
<?= $form->field($model, 'payments_ids')->checkboxList(ArrayHelper::map($paymentsModel,'id','title'),[
    'item'=>function ($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
        return '<div class="col-md-6">'.Html::checkbox($name,$checked,['label'=>$label,'value'=>$value]).'</div>';
    }
]); ?>
```

ну а то, что разделится на 2 колонки - тут bootstrap css нам поможет.

Что не решилось: разделение на колонки и правильный ввод хоть и работает, но разделилось не совсем так, как хотелось. а именно: 
массив [1,2,3,4,5,6] сейчас отображается как

```
1 - 2
3 - 4
5 - 6
```

А хотелось бы все-же вот так

```
1 - 4
2 - 5 
3 - 6
```

Поэтому не буду ставить статус "Решено", может кто-то подскажет как это решить?

UPD:

Если вам не важна сортировка, тогда можно смело использовать способ, описанный выше. Мне она была важна. И вот как это решается.

Как и в вопросе, я разделил массив на части (на 2 в моем случае). Для того, что бы учитывались все варианты надо генерировать **только один hidden input** с дефолтным значением (когда ни один из чекбоксов не выделен). Реализуется это так:

```
<div class="row">
<?php foreach ($dividedPayments as $key => $payments):?>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'payments_ids')->checkboxList(ArrayHelper::map($payments,'id','title'),['unselect'=>($key != 0)?null:'']); ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

А именно указанием значения параметра `unselect` в опциях checkboxList, в моем случае с проверкой `['unselect'=>($key != 0)?null:'']`

Вопрос можно считать закрытым. Надеюсь это кому-то поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Все куда проще

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'permissions')->checkboxList($model->getPermissions()) ?>

#roleform-permissions {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 300px;
    max-height: 100px;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это решение в принципе работает, но далеко не на всех браузерах. К примеру, на IE оно будет работать начиная с 11 версии. 
Про поддержку FLEX можно посмотреть тут. 
https://caniuse.com/#search=flex

На других оно отобразиться отвратительно. К сожалению, надо учитывать и этот фактор.